# Why is my jQuery text.replace() function skipping some characters in strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have a carousel with some captions on each slide, and a function that checks for the letters LUMAX in each of the captions wrapped in an H4 tag and wraps the letter in a SPAN tag.

```
const arr = ['l','u','m','a','x'];
const re = new RegExp(`\\b${arr.join("|")}\\b`,"gi");
$("h4").html((_,text) => text.replace(re,match => `<span>${match}</span>`));
```

I thought this was working correctly, but on closer inspection it is not working for all characters. For instance - on the first slide all is good, but on the second slide the caption reads:

`<h4>Love has no labels</h4>`

For some reason it outputs like this

```
<h4><span>L</span>ove h<span>a</span>s no <span>l</span><span>a</span>bels</h4>
```

As you can see the first and second "L" are wrapped in SPAN tags, however the third instance of the letter L is not.

I tried rewriting the function in vanilla Javascript but this didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove boundary `\b` from your regex and all is well.

Example:

```js
const arr = ['l', 'u', 'm', 'a', 'x'];
const re = new RegExp(`${arr.join("|")}`, "gi");

$("h4").html((_, text) => text.replace(re, match => `<span>${match}</span>`));
```

```css
span {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Love has no labels</h4>
```

Comment: This stood out to me too, but can you explain why they get the result that they do? `\\b${arr.join("|")}\\b` resolves to `\bl|u|m|a|x\b`, which should mean that no L character should be found at all (because it is only to be found when accompanied by backslack and b '\bl\. With that regex, only the `a` characters should be found, but testing it I get the same result as them. I'm a little baffled!

Comment: Boundary rules: 1.Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
2. After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
3.Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.   Fail 3rd option with boundary

Comment: But it's not a boundary. They escape the backslash. They're literally looking for `\b`. Edit: i get different results if I use `new RegExp(\`\\b${arr.join("|")}\\b\`,"gi");` and `new RegExp(\`\bl|u|m|a|x\b\`. "gi");`. The latter gives me the results I expect. The former gives the results the OP says, and it's confusing the hell out of me. (Also the latter is the result of `console.log((\`\\b${arr.join("|")}\\b\`)`;

Comment: I have to study this more in-depth before I can truly say I understand why this works, but it definitely does! Thanks a lot @4b0